# Match Documents where all array members do not contain a value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**MongoDB** selectors become quickly complicated, especially when you come from **mySQL** using `JOIN` and other fancy keywords. I did my best to make the title of this question as clear as possible, but failed miserably.

As an example, let a MongoDB collection have the following schema for its documents:

```
{
    _id : int
    products : [
        {
            qte : int
            status : string
        },            
        {
            qte : int
            status : string
        },
        {
            qte : int
            status : string
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to run a `db.collection.find({ })` query returning documents where **all** products **do not** have the string "finished" as status. Please note that the `products` array has a variable length.

We could also say we want all documents that has at least one product with a status that is not "finished".

If I were to run it as a *Javascript loop*, we would have something like the following :

```
// Will contain queried documents
var matches = new Array();

// The documents variable contains all documents of the collection
for (var i = 0, len = documents.length; i < len; i++) {
    var match = false;

    if (documents[i].products && documents[i].products.length !== 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < documents[i].products; j++) {
            if (documents[i].products[j].status !== "finished") {
                match = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } 

    if (match) {
        matches.push(documents[i]);
    }
}

// The previous snippet was coded directly in the Stack Overflow textarea; I might have done nasty typos.
```

The `matches` array would contain the documents I'm looking for. Now, I wish there would be a way of doing something similar to `collection.find({"products.$.status" : {"$ne":"finished"}})` but MongoDB hates my face when I do so.

Also, documents that do not have any products need to be ignored, but I already figured this one out with a `$and` clause. Please note that I need the **ENTIRE** document to be returned, not just the product array. If a document has products that are not "finished", then the entire document should be present. If a document has all of its products set at "finished", the document is not returned at all.

**MongoDB Version**: 3.2.4

**Example**

Let's say we have a collection that contains three documents.

This one would match because one of the status is not "finished".

```
{
    _id : 1,
    products : [
        {
            qte : 10,
            status : "finished"
        },
        {
            qte : 21,
            status : "ongoing"
        },
    ]
}
```

This would not match because all statuses are set to "finished"

```
{
    _id : 2,
    products : [
        {
            qte : 35,
            status : "finished"
        },
        {
            qte : 210,
            status : "finished"
        },
        {
            qte : 2,
            status : "finished"
        },
    ]
}
```

This would also not match because there are no products. It would also not match if the `products` field was undefined.

```
{
    _id : 3,
    products : []
}
```

Again, if we ran the query in a collection that had the three documents in this example, the output would be:

```
[
    {
        _id : 1,
        products : [
            {
                qte : 10,
                status : "finished"
            },
            {
                qte : 21,
                status : "ongoing"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Only the first document gets returned because it has at least one product that doesn't have a status of "finished", but the last two did not make the cut since they either have all their products' statuses set as "finished", or don't have any products at all.

Comment: So help me understanding in plain English! Are you trying to find documents where status is finished but want to exclude documentation not having status?

Comment: @Saleem As mentioned in the second paragraph, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Documents where all objects contained in the "products" array have the field "status" different than "finished".

Comment: Sounds good. So products array may have more than one `status` field? If this is the case, please update your post with a complete sample document.

Comment: @Saleem No. The array contains objects. The objects have one `status` field each. Have a look at the first block of text. It represents a document schema. The array `products` contains objects which all have a `status` field.

Comment: Got it. check out my post below. hopefully its what are you looking for.

Comment: yw. quite there. can you run this query and post result. `db.collection.findOne()`

Comment: @Saleem I unfortunately cannot as the document is huge and has fields that I am not allowed to share online. I added examples at the end of the questions where one document would match and where one would not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following query. It's fetching documents where  status is not equals to `"finished"`

> Note: This query will work with MongoDB 3.2+ only

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $project:{
        "projectid" : 1,
        "campname" : 1,
        "campstatus" : 1,
        "clientid" : 1,
        "paymentreq" : 1,
        products:{
          $filter:{
            input:"$products", 
            as: "product", 
            cond:{$ne: ["$$product.status", "finished"]}
           }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $match:{"products":{$gt: [0, {$size:"products"}]}}
    }
])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it will only check if the first object of the `products` array have a field status that does not equal "finished". I ran the query in a collection that contains a document with two products where only one has the status "finished" and it did not returned the document. All products in the array must have a status of "finished" for the query to ignore the document. Huh, this is so complicated.

Comment: Well this is the reason I asked you to update a real document sample with multiple products. Posting schema is not enough. Also mention your MongoDB version too.

Comment: All done! Thanks for helping, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Got the following error : Failed to parse: filter: [ { $project: { products: { $filter: { input: \"$products\", as: \"product\", cond: { $ne: [ \"$$product.status\", \"finished\" ] } } } } } ]. 'filter' field must be of BSON type Object.

Comment: are you sure you have MongoDB 3.2? try above query in MongoDB shell.

Comment: "mongod --version" prints "db version v3.2.4", so yes. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, but it shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107677/discussion-between-saleem-and-erik-desjardins).

Answer (score 2):

You need `.aggregate()` rather than `.find()` here. That is the only way to determine if **ALL** elements actually don't contain what you want:

```js
// Sample data
db.products.insertMany([
  { "products": [
    { "qte": 1 },
    { "status": "finished" },
    { "status": "working" }
  ]},
  { "products": [
    { "qte": 2 },
    { "status": "working" },
    { "status": "other" }
  ]}
])
```

Then the aggregate operation with [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/):

```js
db.products.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$anyElementTrue": [
          { "$map": {
            "input": "$products",
            "as": "product",
            "in": { 
              "$eq": [ "$$product.status", "finshed" ]
            }
          }}
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$PRUNE",
      "else": "$$KEEP"
    }
  }}
])
```

Or alternately you can use the poorer and slower cousin with [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)

```js
db.products.find(function(){
  return !this.products.some(function(product){
    return product.status == "finished"
  })
})
```

Both return just the one sample document:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56fb4791ae26432047413455"),
        "products" : [
                {
                        "qte" : 2
                },
                {
                        "status" : "working"
                },
                {
                        "status" : "other"
                }
        ]
}
```

So the `$anyElementTrue` with the `$map` input or the `.some()` are basically doing the same thing here and evaluating if there was any match at all. You use the "negative" assertion to "exclude" documents that actually find a match.

Comment: That would definitely work if the collection contained the arrays "directly". Problem is the `products` array is contained inside a document. I tried running the query and it ran first try, but returned all documents. Please use the sample data I provided at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @ÉrikDesjardins I think you are getting confused by the fact I also called the collection `"products"`. All data is of course represented within an "array" also called `"products"` here. So look again. Carefully this time.

Comment: Right, my bad. Sorry about that-- But the query still returns all values, even those with all statuses as "finished" or with no products in the array.

Comment: @ÉrikDesjardins No it does not, and the example here proves it. You are probably feeling a bit worn down by your own frustration and the babble you have been enduring for the last hour now. Take a breath, run the example and see the results. You certainly did not take it in just a few minutes. Relax and you will see I'm right.

Comment: I really don't want to argue with you as you're a lot more experienced than me with MongoDB. If you look at the pastebin link, I ran the query you provided, and got documents where objects contained in the `projects` array have all `"status" : "finished"`. Those are not supposed to be returned. Object with an empty `projects` array should not be returned either. If you look at the output of your query (also on paste bin). you'll see two documents returned. Both should not be there.

Comment: @ÉrikDesjardins Your "question" **does not** ask for "filtering" of the array. This is returning the documents "as is". **But** the **only** documents returned are those where **no** array member contains "finshed". That is what you asked. Doccument selection and "filtering" are two different things.

Comment: First part is correct; it should return the documents "as is". Maybe I used the wrong vocabulary? I basically want to get all documents (entire document as is) from a collection, where all the objects contained in the array located in the field `projects`, do not have the status set as "finished". If one of them doesn't have the status set as "finished", the entire document gets returned. The three examples at the bottom of the "question" should help.